# jwt gem undefined method 'verify' for String

Tags: ruby, jwt

I'm attempting to use the jwt gem.  I've got everything set up according to the recommendations in the docs.  When I hit my endpoint and pass the header, I get the above error.  I've narrowed it down to the verify_rsa method on line 61.

```
def verify_rsa(algorithm, public_key, signing_input, signature)
  public_key.verify(OpenSSL::Digest.new(algorithm.sub('RS', 'sha')), signature, signing_input)
end
```

The public_key local variable is what's throwing the error.  It is a string.  I'm not even really sure where to find the verify method that's being called.  The only one I see is in decode.rb and it doesn't take 4 arguments.  Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm using jwt version 1.5.6.

Comment: To use RSA with ruby-jwt, you have to pass in an RSA public key object. You can load the private key and call `#public_key` on it to get the public key. Do you already have a key pair and if so in which format?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue, here's how to turn a public key stored as a plain string into a JWT-ready OpenSSL PublicKey object:

```rb
public_key = OpenSSL::PKey.read(public_key)
```